# Popover content when mouse over a button in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, popover

I have a table of cell formatted in grid.i.e. 5 rows of 10 cells. 
Each cell represents a slot which contains some information about the item in the slot. 
The cell is formatted to a button, when I click on it, it directs me to a page where user can edit the item name, type, and other information, just like a normal rails edit function.

My question is that I other than directing user to the edit page, I want them to see some of the attributes about that slot. So that, if they see the information they need, they can click the slot and edit on a new page.

right now, I have tried to use CSS and javascript to hide and show a div tag which stores the information, but when I mouse over the div just mess up the arrangement of the cells.

I have read about using AJAX to render the page, but I cannot understand how to make it with popovers when mouse over the button.

This is my table of cells in index.html.erb

```
<div class="scrollWindow">
  <% @slots.each_with_index do |item,index| %>
    <div class="vmRow">
      <div class="btn-group">

      <% for i in item do %>     
        <% if !VendingMachine1.where(:slotID => i).first.nil? %>
        <% vm = VendingMachine1.where(:slotID => i).first %>
          <%= link_to  vending_machine1_path(vm.id),:class=>"vmButton", :method => :get do %>
            <div class="myPara"><%= i %> </div>
            <div class="myPara">Q:<%= find_vm_quantity(vm) %> </div>
            <div class="myPara">P:<%= vm.priority %></div>
            <div class="myPara" ><%= vm.identifier %></div>
            <% end %>
        <% else %>
            <div class="vmButton">
            <div class="myPara"><%= i %> </div>
            <div class="myPara">Q:-</div>
            <div class="myPara">P:-</div>
            <div class="myPara">-</div>
            </div>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>

     </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

my controller

```
  def index
    @vending_machine1s = VendingMachine1.all.order(:slotID).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
    @total_quantity = VendingMachine1.sum(:quantity)
    @slots =[["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5" ,"A6", "A7", "A8", "A9", "A0"],
             ["B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "B5", "B6", "B7", "B8", "B9", "B0"],
             ["C1", "C2", "C3", "C4", "C5", "C6", "C7", "C8", "C9", "C0"],
             ["D1", "D2", "D3", "D4", "D5", "D6", "D7", "D8", "D9", "D0"],
             ["E1", "E2", "E3", "E4", "E5", "E6", "E7", "E8", "E9", "E0"]]

  end
```

I have read about popover from bootstrap, but I can only set data-content like simple texts, however, I need to display more information of model, so I think I have to go through the controller?

The ideal solution is when I mouse over each cell, a small popover window will show the information of the cell, when I move my mouse away, it disappears, and likewise for all the cells.

Please help. This is too challenging.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `position: absolute` to avoid messing html.

On JsFiddle i provide some example.
https://jsfiddle.net/bgzzzpe3/

Comment: hmm, I tried your method, but the content div still appears somewhere else.